# neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovs_neutron_agent [-] Bridge enp125s0f0 for physical network provider does not exist. Agent terminated

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron, debian-bookworm

My operating system is Debian 12.

I deployed openstack cluster with two nodes, controller34 is control node, worker35 is work node, no extra network node, my network planning is work node and network node reuse, I deployed neutron Self-service networks according to the official website document, found the following error in the log of control node
**that's my ip conf**

```
root@controller34:/home/dky# cat /etc/network/interfaces
## This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
## and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
#
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp125s0f0
iface enp125s0f0 inet static
        address 192.168.203.34/24
        gateway 192.168.203.254
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 192.168.203.11
```

**that's my error log**

```
tail -100f /var/log/neutron/neutron-openvswitch-agent.log
2024-01-23 10:54:52.946 241411 ERROR neutron.plugins.ml2.drivers.openvswitch.agent.ovs_neutron_agent [-] Bridge enp125s0f0 for physical network provider does not exist. Agent terminated!
2024-01-23 10:54:56.939 241421 INFO neutron.common.config [-] Logging enabled!
```

that's my conf file

1. `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini`

```
cat /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini
[ml2]
# ...
type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan
tenant_network_types = vxlan
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch,l2population
extension_drivers = port_security

[ml2_type_flat]
# ...
flat_networks = provider

[ml2_type_vxlan]
# ...
vni_ranges = 1:1000
```

2. `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini`

```
root@controller34:/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2# cat /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini
[ovs]
bridge_mappings = provider:enp125s0f0

[vxlan]
local_ip = 192.168.203.34
l2_population = true

[securitygroup]
# ...
enable_security_group = true
firewall_driver = openvswitch
#firewall_driver = iptables_hybrid
```

I found no error in the log of the work node .

that's my ip config:

```
root@controller34:/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0f0np0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:8c:b6:16:27:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp125s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:16:e7:95:13:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.203.34/24 brd 192.168.203.255 scope global enp125s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a616:e7ff:fe95:130b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I tried to create the bridge manually, but it didn't work.
Currently, we are still in the testing phase, so I am planning to use a single network interface to build the External network, management network, tenant network.

Answer (score 0):

The bridge mapping requires a bridge, not an interface, but it's not entirely clear from the [docs](https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/2023.2/install/controller-install-option2-ubuntu.html). But the config option `bridge_mappings` is pretty clear. I don't have an OVN setup yet so this is for a OVS deployment as you also seem to require:

```
# create provider bridge on control node
ovs-vsctl add-br br-provider

# add port to provider bridge (physnet is probably enp125s0f0 in your case)
ovs-vsctl add-port br-provider {{ physnet }}

# edit /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini

[ovs]
bridge_mappings = provider:br-provider
```

After you edited the the config file restart the `neutron-openvswitch-agent.service`, maybe even all neutron services on the control node. Then do the same on the compute node as it also requires a bridge mapping. If you intend to use an external (provider) network, you'll need another interface without an IP configured.